# How to find the value of $\sin24^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

Is there any method to do it by hand quickly? i want to show the angle $72$ can be trisected by compass and ruler. so i need to find the way to calculate it... help please!

Comment: The $\sin 72^\circ$ is much easier to find than $\sin 24^\circ$. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1823923/complex-numbers-and-binomial-expansion/1823959#1823959) shows that $\cos\frac{\pi}{10}=\cos 18^\circ=\sin 72^\circ=\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt{5}}{8}}$, confirming that $72^\circ$ is constructible since it only has square roots in its $\sin$.

Comment: i am sorry i meant to calculate sin24 to see 72 can be trisected. i editted the question

Comment: A [pentadecagon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentadecagon) can be constructed.

Comment: Related: [This answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1541219/409) shows a general form of values of $\sin k 3^\circ$ for integer $k$. Since the values involve nothing more complicated than square roots, they're constructible.

Comment: $$\sin(60-36)^\circ=?$$ and use http://www.intmath.com/blog/mathematics/how-do-you-find-exact-values-for-the-sine-of-all-angles-6212

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that $60^\circ$ can be constructed and that $72^\circ$ can be constructed. By bisecting the $72^\circ$, we get $36^\circ$ and by subtracting the $60^\circ$ by the $36^\circ$, we get $24^\circ$. Thus, $24^\circ$ is constructable and $72^\circ$ can be trisected.